# Find the value of a record an return it back from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a stored procedure that accepts the value of a unique item from my table and searches for it in that table. If it exists return back the value of the primary key column of that row. If it doesn't exists then just return 1234 for now for testing purposes.

So that's how I wrote it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyTestSP
    @ExID VARCHAR(64)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ExIDPK INT;

    SELECT  @ExIDPK = ExPK
    FROM 
        dbo.EXIDs
    WHERE 
        EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EXIDs WHERE ExID = @ExID);

    IF @ExID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        RETURN @ExIDPK;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1234;
    END;
END;
```

and this is for testing how I call it:

```
EXEC MyTestSP 'ewedweweewe';
```

but it always returns this:

> Procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why you are using `EXISTS()` in the `WHERE` clause? and why don't you just select the PK or use an OUTPUT parameter?

Comment: I mean, you are using: `IF @ExID IS NOT NULL`, and you know it's not null because you are giving it a value. Doesn't mean that the value that you gave it has a match on the dbo.ExIDs table...so @ExIDPK might be a null

Comment: Also you have a semicolon in `END;` which is wrong there and you don't need the `IF` at all, just make it simple and set the default value of your variable to 1234.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things.

- Your if check was wrong. You were checking `@ExID` instead of `@ExIDPK` and `@ExID` isn't null-able based on your proc definition
- I suggest that you change the `exist` logic to a simpler `where` clause as well

see code below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyTestSP
    @ExID VARCHAR(64)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ExIDPK INT;

    SELECT  @ExIDPK = ExPK
    FROM 
        dbo.EXIDs
    WHERE ExID = @ExID;

        RETURN ISNULL(@ExIDPK,1234);

END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking to your procedure, you declare the variable as `DECLARE @ExIDPK INT;`, so the default value is `NULL`. That makes your SP return `NULL` if the value passed is not exists in your table, and that's why you get this message.

Also, there is no need to use `EXISTS()` in the where clause, since you have the parameter, just a simple check will do the job. And you have an extra semicolon in the `END` of the `IF`

```
IF @ExID IS NOT NULL -- you are checking the wrong variable here too
BEGIN
    RETURN @ExIDPK;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    RETURN 1234;
END;--This one
```

which is wrong, and you don't need an `IF` at all, just make it simple as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyTestSP
    @ExID VARCHAR(64)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ExIDPK INT = 1234; --Will ensure your variable never be NULL

    SELECT  @ExIDPK = ExPK
    FROM 
        dbo.EXIDs
    WHERE ExID = @ExID;

        RETURN @ExIDPK;

END;
```

That will ensure your variable never be `NULL`, because you set the default value which won't changed if your query returns no rows (0 rows).

Finally, I would recommand to use an OUTPUT parameter (or even a SELECT) instead of using the `RETURN` code.

> Return codes are commonly used in control-of-flow blocks within procedures to set the return code value for each possible error situation

See **[Return Data from a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)**

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was posed based on understanding the mechanism for returning a value, I'm going to post this as more of a preferred mechanism. Typically return codes / return values are reserved for error codes with 0 being success, and non-0 being something other than success (with the notable exception being SQL Server Agent run_status.

The code sample below will allow you to test different scenario:

```
if object_id(N'[test].[table_01]', N'U') is not null
  drop table [test].[table_01];

go

create table [test].[table_01]
  (
     [id]      [int] identity(1, 1) not null,
          constraint [test__table_01__id__pk] primary key clustered([id])
     , [value] varchar(64)
  );

go

insert into [test].[table_01]
            ([value])
values      ('red'),
            ('green'),
            ('blue');

go

if object_id(N'[test].[get__name__id]', N'P') is not null
  drop procedure [test].[get__name__id];

go

create procedure [test].[get__name__id] @value varchar(64)
                                        , @id  [int] = null output
as
  begin
      set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
      set NOCOUNT on;

      select @id = [id]
      from   [test].[table_01]
      where  [value] = @value;
  end;

go

--
declare @pk      [int]= null
        , @value [varchar](64)='test';

execute [test].[get__name__id]
  @value=@value
  , @id=@pk output;

if @pk is not null
  begin
      select @pk      as [primary_key__for__value]
             , @value as [value];
  end;
else
  begin
      select 'No primary key found for value ' + @value;
  end;
```